# How can I have an "implicit multiplication" rule with Bison?

Tags: bison

I'm working on a Bison file for a mathematical expression parser. Up to now it's mostly fine, but I'm facing a problem with implicit multiplications.

You see, I'd like to support expressions like `2x sin(4x) cos(4x)`. It should parse like `2 * x * sin(4 * x) * cos(4 * x)`. Nothing too bad here, but consider the following set of rules:

```
expr
    : /* snip */
    | '-' expr      { /* negate expression */ }
    | expr '-' expr { /* subtract expressions */ }
    | expr expr     { /* multiply expressions */ }
```

Having that implicit multiplication rule creates an ambiguity with the subtraction rule: is `x - log(x)` the subtraction of `log(x)` to `x` or the multiplication of `x` by `-log(x)`?

I'd be ready to settle for an easy solution, like "it's a multiplication unless it's subtracting", but I don't know how to tell that to Bison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Having that implicit multiplication rule creates an ambiguity with the subtraction rule: is x - log(x) the subtraction of log(x) to x or the multiplication of x by -log(x)?

Or even, is it `x - l * o * g * x`? Or maybe just `x - log * x`?

So not quite a simple problem. Suppose you can tell just by looking at `log` that it is a function. Then you can disambiguate in your lexer, and you're left with "in case of doubt, an operator that looks like an infix operator is an infix operator". Here's a quick solution:

```
term   : ID
       | NUMBER
       | '(' expr ')'      { $$ = $2; }
       | FUNC '(' expr ')' { $$ = new_expr($1, 'c', $3); }
       ;

factor : term
       | term factor       { $$ = new_expr($1, '*', $2); }
       ;

prefix : factor
       | '-' factor        { $$ = new_expr(0, '-', $2); }
       ;

muldiv : prefix
       | muldiv '/' prefix { $$ = new_expr($1, '/', $3); }
       | muldiv '*' prefix { $$ = new_expr($1, '*', $3); }
       ;

expr   : muldiv
       | expr '+' muldiv { $$ = new_expr($1, '+', $3); }
       | expr '-' muldiv { $$ = new_expr($1, '-', $3); }
       ;
```

This particular grammar disallows --x, although it's perfectly happy with y--x, which means y-(-x). If you want to accept --x, you could change the second `prefix` production to `'-' prefix`.

Personally, I'd prefer to be able to type `sin 2x` and `log 3n` but that starts to get a bit tricky. What does `sin 2x cos 2x` mean? Presumably, it means `(sin(2*x))*(cos(2*x))`. But does `log nlog n` not mean `log(n*log(n))` ? This can all be achieved; it just requires thinking through all the possibilities.

Comment: Well, it's not `x * l * o * g` because my lexer sees "log" (and, for that matter, all supported function names) as a distinct token and my parser handles functions with a specific rule.

Comment: @zneak, yes, I guessed that. Hence the use of FUNC as a lexical token in my grammar :)